# Sinch is not working between Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am using Sinch SDK and its SDK is proper implemented in both Android and in IOS. Android to Android and IOS to IOS chat is proper working. Issue is occurring in Cross platform (Android to IOS and vice versa).
In Android, controls enters in onMessageFailed method and gives "usernotfound" message and same is happening in IOS with giving "usernotfound" message.

Code is very huge to write here, please provide a solution for cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

if you get user now found, then you are trying to call a user that have not yet logged in to you app and started the sinch client with that username

Comment: Same problem with cross platform, I get success in Android & iOS when i login but unable to send/receive message.

Comment: Yupp, you need to start the clients with the same app key at least once. other wise it wound work